# How do I publish a app in the chrome web store?

Tags: chrome-web-store

Edit: There's no workaround.

(Sorry if this is a duplicate, I didn't find anything like this, and also sorry if this is a dumb question)
I've been trying to publish a app to the chrome web store, so I paid US$5 to create a account, set it up, set up the extension, saved as draft, and then clicked 'Why can I not publish?', and then I saw "The chrome web store does not allow new apps.", I was thinking, "What? How is there all these apps in the chrome web store?" and I'm still thinking. Does somebody understand how to publish one? or can you not anymore?
[image: pain]

Comment: I think you are confusing Chrome apps and Chrome extensions. Chrome Web Store stopped accepting new apps in 2020.

Comment: Oh.............